Why is Castle.Core being added as a dependency to my Nuget package?
I created a VERY basic .NetStandard2.1 class library -- a single class with a single interface.  I built the solution and committed to Azure DevOps.
I created a build Pipeline that compiles the library, creates a nuget package and publishes the package to Azure Artifacts.
I then created a .Net 8 console application and used the NuGet Package Manager to load my package from the Azure Artifacts.  When I select the package in Package Manager, it shows no dependencies (which is what I expected).  But when I try to install it, it shows that it is installing Castle.Core.3.3.3 along with my NuGetTestlib.1.0.0.
Where is Castle.Core.3.3.3 coming from?  Why is that being installed as part of my package?
Class Library
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Compute(int number1, int number2, char operation)
    {
        switch (operation)
        {
           case '+':
               return number1 + number2;
               break;
           case '-':
               return number1 - number2;
               break;

           default:
               throw new Exception($"Operation '{operation}' is not supported.");
       }
    }
}

public interface ICalculator
{
    public int Compute(int number1, int number2, char operation);
}

That is my complete class library.  No added dependencies or NuGet packages.
Library Project File
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>




Update
This morning, I updated my pipeline yaml to include versioning.  Prior to this I had the following:
Original Yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack $(ProjectName)'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: '$(ProjectPath)'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Publish $(ProjectName)'
  inputs:
    command: push
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'MyProject/NugetSharedTest'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    allowPackageConflicts: true

Updated Yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack $(ProjectName)'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: '$(ProjectPath)'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: byBuildNumber

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Publish $(ProjectName)'
  inputs:
    command: push
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'MyProject/NugetSharedTest'
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
    allowPackageConflicts: false

After doing this, it forced my next run of the pipeline to build a new version of my NuGet package. (I'm assuming the original code was simply overwriting the existing version).  In creating a new version, it seems to have gotten rid of the Castle.Core reference.  While I still don't understand where that reference came from -- it seems like the new versioning helped resolve the issue.

Are you installing the package in Visual Studio or VS Code? If yes, can you share the screenshot about the details of the package in Nuget Package Manger? Other than the unexpected pacakge: Castle.Core, are there any other dependencies packages exists in project?

If possible, can you share a Minimal Reproducible Example of the class library? This will be helpful to investigate the issue further.

Another thing that is weird is that the library clearly targets the .NetStandard library -- but when I first installed the package, it was actually loaded as .NetFramework so it conflicted with the .Net 8 app that I was installing it in.   Not sure if that is related or helpful or not, but I thought I'd mention it.

Weird -- this morning, I updated my pipeline to use the build number to create versioning of my packages -- once I created a new version, Castle.Core went away and I was able to succesfully load my library.

Glad to know that the newer version can help you solve the issue. I guess it might be some cache of local VS that caused some unrelated packages to be accidentally installed.  But thanks for sharing the information anyway. Could you consider adding your current approach to the answer? It might help someone with the same issue.
